# Pass existing data after edit button was clicked to ejs from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
connection.query('update customers set ? where id ='+ req.params.id, user, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash('error', err);

      //Since there is an error need to render back the edit page
      res.render('/customers/edit', {
         title: 'Edit Customer',
         id: req.params.id,
         name: 'select Name from customers where id='+req.params.id,
         email: 'select Email from customers where id='+req.params.id
      })
    } else {
         req.flash('success', 'Data updated successfully!');
         res.redirect('/customers');
    }
 })
```

edit.ejs:

```
<body>
<%= console.log(id) %>
<form action="/customers/update/<%= id %>" method="post" name="form1">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="<%= name %>" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" value="<%= email %>">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
</body>
```

I am fresh in NodeJS, I am trying to get name and email as default values from existing name and email values after clicking on edit button. If i console.log(id), it logs in the id in the console, however, name and email is undefined if i log them, I am not sure how to pass them in `res.render` to be able to access it in template, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).  I can pass a query, such as '1 UNION DROP TABLE user', into the path '/customers/update/' and basically do whatever I want with your DB.

You need to assemble your query like this:

```
var sql = 'UPDATE customers SET someColumn = ?, someOtherColumn = ? WHERE id = ?';
```

Then execute the query like this:

```
var params = ['someValue', 'someOtherValue', 1];
connection.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
if (err) { //do something

}
});
```

Now, on your res.render, you are trying to pass `'select Name from customers where id='+req.params.id` which will set the value of `name` equal to the query, not the *result* of the query.

If you want to pass the *result* of the query to the template, then you will have to run an additional `connection.query`.  It would look something like this:

```
var params = ['someValue', 'someOtherValue', 1];
connection.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
if (err) { //do something
    connection.query('SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], function(err, result) {
      if (err) { //do something
          res.render('/customers/edit', {
            title: 'Edit Customer',
            id: req.params.id,
            name: result[0],
            email: result[1]
          });
      }
    });
}
});
```